# Blender 2.8 textures not showing up in EEVEE and LookDev

Tags: texturing

With a clean install of Blender 2.8 on OSX when I apply a texture like Gradient or Checkers on a Principled BSDF shader it only shows it on the object in Cycles, not in EEVEE and Look Dev mode.
Rendering gives the same result as the viewport.

Cycles:
[image]

EEVEE:
[image]

Is this normal behaviour or am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: THIS IS INCORRECT.**

This is normal, as these textures are not used in EEVEE. EEVEE only uses the standard "Texture" node, which references the textures in the "Texture" tab of Properties. Unfortunately, Checker Textures cannot be generated in EEVEE.

**(THIS IS CORRECT)**
I'm not actually sure. (I was thinking of the wrong engine.)

Comment: Alright, thanks.

Comment: @Erik81 You're welcome.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zrd37k2tJM&list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6&index=17
This is weird, in this tutorial he is showing the gradient texture in look dev mode. Isn't Look Dev also using Eevee?

Comment: @Erik81 Honestly, I'm not sure. Sorry

Comment: Oh wow...sorry. I thought EEVEE was the same as Internal! Sorry. I don't really know what's going on then.

Comment: No worries.
Did some fiddling, when I create a Texture Coordinate node and connect UV from that to the Vector from the Checker texture node the checkers finally shows in Look Dev and Eevee. Strange why this differs from the tutorial video.